# Move Trello boards between organizations

Tags: trello

I'd like to move a board to a different organization, but it appears that the organization can't be changed once set.

Is it at all possible to move boards around like this?

Answer (score 34):

While this wasn't possible in early version of Trello, you can now change the team that a board is in.

1. Go to the board
2. (On the right, Click "Show Menu" if it's not already open)
3. Click "More..."
4. Click "Settings"
5. Click "Change Team"
6. Select from the list

[image: screen shot of menu]

Answer (score 13):

This appears to have changed.

1. On the board, show the sidebar if it's not already open, by clicking on *Show sidebar* or by pressing <kbd>w</kbd>
2. Click on **Menu** and expand it if necessary.
3. Click **Additional Settings**.
4. Then click **Change Organization** and choose your organization as above.

Comment: "Additional Settings" doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @VebjornLjosa I've used "Additional Settings" today. Perhaps your not an admin of the Board you viewed.

Comment: Now you follow step 1., then select *... More*, then *Settings* and profit. *Change Organization* is in there -- as of right now, anyhow.

Answer (score 7):

1. Click "Board Menu"
2. Click "Profile"
3. In the Organization section, click the "Change" link

[image: The "Change" link]

**Note**: You'll need to own the board that you're modifying, and you'll need to be a member of the organization that you're transferring the board to

Comment: Not correct any more. Other two answers show the current way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the organization to which a board belongs

[image]

You can change the organization that a board belongs to by opening the right sidebar on the board, clicking "Menu", then "Additional Settings", and then "Change Organization." Select the organization you would like your board to belong to from the drop down menu or select "none" if you do not want your board to belong to an organization.

NOTE: You have to be an admin of the board to change its organization.

[image]
Change the org a board belongs to from the board's settings.
You can also change the organization that a board is associated with by clicking the organization's name in your board's header to the right of your board's name, selecting "Change Organization" and then choosing the organization you would like to now associate your board with.

Or change the organization a board belongs to from the board's header.

Answer (score 0):

As of Jul 2019, one of the easy approaches is to simply share the board with the new Trello user account and then delete  ( depends on your use case, you could also 'leave' the board if you are not owner of the board) that board from the old account.

This is my take on synthetic equivalent to 'Move Trello boards between organizations' as per OP's question.

Add member in Trello:

[image]

Change permission to Admin:

[image]