# Within Trello, is it possible to transfer a board to another organization?

Tags: trello, trello-organization, migrate-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Move Trello boards between organizations](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19271/move-trello-boards-between-organizations)

Within Trello, is it possible to transfer a board to another organization? I created/started a board and later found it was better suited to be categorized under a separate organization which I have created.